# How to allow negative and positive values from 0 to 100 for an input box in Angular 6?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

HTML code

```
  <input type="number" min="0" max="100" required placeholder="Charge" [(ngModel)]="rateInput" name="rateInput" [formControl]="rateControl">
```

TypeScript validation

```
this.rateControl = new FormControl("", [Validators.max(100), Validators.min(0)]);
```

This will allow only positive values. What if we need to validate for both positive and negative values from 0 to 100?

Comment: Have you tried min -100?

Answer (score 0):

[check number field added here](https://angular-6-reactive-form-validation.stackblitz.io)

```
<input type="number" required min="-100" max="400" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" >
```